# MFC: Conflicting information on how to clean up after using COleDataSource::DoDragDrop()

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, mfc, ole

Can someone clear up all the conflicting information.

The documentation for `COleDataSource::CacheData()` says:

> After the call to CacheData the ptd member of lpFormatEtc and the
>   contents of lpStgMedium are owned by the data object, not by the
>   caller.

The documentation for `COleDataSource::CacheGlobalData()` doesn't say that.

You find code examples of how to use `COleDataSource::DoDragDrop()` on places like Code Project which call `COleDataSource::CacheGlobalData()` then check the `DoDragDrop()` results and free the memory if it didn't drop:

```
DROPEFFECT dweffect=datasrc->DoDragDrop(DROPEFFECT_COPY);
// They say if operation wasn't accepted, or was canceled, we 
// should call GlobalFree() to clean up.    
if (dweffect==DROPEFFECT_NONE) {
  GlobalFree(hgdrop);
}
```

You also have Q182219 (which for some unknown reason MS has totally broken all the good old MSKB links and you can't find any information anymore (links all over the Internet are dead). Q182219 says something about after a successful move operation on NT based OS (Win10), it will return `DROPEFFECT_NONE` so you have to check if things really moved.

So the questions are:

1) Should you really free the memory if the drop operation returns `DROPEFFECT_NONE` or would MFC handle all that?

2) Does it still return `DROPEFFFECT_NONE` after a successful move operation or does MFC handle that internally (or fixed in some Windows version) ?

3) If it does return `DROPEFFECT_NONE` after a move, wouldn't logic like the above be a double free on memory if it was a move operation?

Extra:

You also find examples and usage of people doing `COleDataSource mydatasource` which is WRONG.  You have to allocate it like `COleDataSource *mydatasource=new ColeDataSource()` and then at the end use `mydatasource->ExternalRelease()` to release it.  (`ExternalRelease()` handles calling `InternalRelease()` if the object isn't using aggregation (that is a derived class that acts as a wrapper))

TIA!!

Comment: I would expect the `COleDataSource` dtor to free any resources it owns.

Comment: Why not just look at the source code for `COleDataSource` and see what `CacheData()` and `CacheGlobalData()` are actually doing?  Then you will know what they do and do not take ownership of.